# Form popup function is not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, popup

I am trying to open a popup using the function "ShowPopupPanel01". Below is the written function :

```
 function ShowPopupPanel01() {

        debugger;
        var left = 0;// (screen.width / 2) - (330 / 2);
        var top = 0;// (screen.height / 2) - (570 / 2);
       popup =  window.open("RearPanelGeo.aspx?","Popup", 'toolbar=no,fullscreen=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no,titlebar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no,width='+screen.width+',height='+screen.height+', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        popup.focus();
    }
```

And this is the Button whose click the form "RearPanelGeo" should pop up :

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="?" OnClientClick="ShowPopupPanel01"  />
```

However, after clicking on the "Button1" the webpage is giving following errors.[The error says that functiop "ShowPopupPanel01" is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4umY.png)

Please help me in solving the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the JS is being loaded in the browser?? Confirm it by executing the function from the developer console.

Comment: I executed the function "ShowPopupPanel01" in the developer console. It says "Undefined". Thank you Chakri for your swift response.

Comment: It should probably be `OnClientClick="ShowPopupPanel01()"`

Comment: Where did you code your function?? In aspx or JS file? If it is JS file ensure that it is loaded. Give a try as per @James suggestion.

Comment: As @Chakri mentioned make sure that function is being loaded, if you are using Jquery put this function into `$(function(){ /* ... */ });`

Comment: 1. Thank you, Chakri, the function was not being loaded in the js file as there were some curly braces left unclosed in some other functions mentioned in the "<script type="text/javascript">.... </script>" code.

Comment: 1.Thank you, James, the function was not properly called on the "OnClientClick" event. I made some silly mistakes. Thank you so much for responding generously.Stackoverflow is indeed a great platform to develop your skills and be a better programmer.Thank you again.